# awk command in subprocess.Popen - Getting Error

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying this code:This code work fine and gave me the output what i need .

```
import os,sys
import sitenamevalidation
import getpass
import subprocess

site_name = sys.argv[1]


def get_location(site_name):

    site_name_vali = sitenamevalidation.sitenamevalidation(site_name)
    if site_name_vali == True:
            pass
    else:
            print("Sitename should be in this format [a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9] example abc54 or xyz50")
            sys.exit(0)
    site = site_name[:3].upper()
    user =getpass.getuser()
    path = os.path.join('/home/',user,'location.attr')
    if os.path.exists(path) == True:
            pass
    else:
            print("Not able to find below path "+path)

    #p1 = subprocess.Popen(['awk', '/site/{getline; print}' , path] ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(['awk', '/ABC/{getline; print}' , path] ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output=p1.communicate()
    print str(output[0].strip().lower())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_location(site_name)
```

Main issue is if i use   this below  command

```
  p1 = subprocess.Popen(['awk', '/ABC/{getline; print}' , path] ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

where ABC is static value in path it work fine and give me desired output  but i wanted the value which user will enter (site in my code). When i am doing this

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['awk', '/site/{getline; print}' , path] ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

It is looking for site in that file which is not there.I want the value of site variable  to go in that command rather the site itself.Tried different by putting quote , double quote but nothing seem to be working.

Comment: What is there inside `get_data_location`?

Comment: I have updated the full code above.Sorry I am new to python so some of the code is not very good.

Comment: You're sure `/home/user/xyz.attr` exists on your filesystem? What's the output of `ls /home/user/xyz.attr` in your shell?

Comment: ls /home/user/xyz.attr is